# Error on Adding Master Page.

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a using `ASP.net C#` firstly I have created a *webform* `FrmFirst.aspx`. Then I have created a `master page`. Now I have to add my *first page* to *master page* then I am facing the same error :

[image]

I am using this code to add my *first page* to *Master page*

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" CodeFile="FrmCustomerMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="FrmCustomerMaster" %>
```

Tell me my Problem !! Thanks ....

Comment: It's much easier to do this backwards - create a master page then add the form to it!

Comment: Can you show more of the markup of FirstPage

Comment: Can you add the markup code of `MasterPage.master` and `FrmCustomerMaster.aspx`?

Comment: @Liath Don't tell me add master page. Tell me how to prevent this above error after adding ?

Comment: @ekad I am only change in code that I have shown above.Do you telling about that ?

Comment: @Shrawan that's why I gave a comment not an answer - have you tried doing what I suggested and comparing the two?

Comment: No, I would like to know if `FrmCustomerMaster.aspx` still contains `<html>`,`<head>`, or `<form>` tags. Also if it contains the correct ContentPlaceHolders as defined in the master page.

Comment: yes every time when i am doing this same error I got...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your body to content sections. The master page works with contentplaceholders: your content pages need to provide the content for these placeholders
see [LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

if your master page contain this code

```
<asp:contentplaceholder id="Main" runat="server" />
```

your page that Inherits from master should have

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
```